# HTML code in PL/SQL proc- background image code for embedding dynamic images

Tags: html, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am brand new to html and am writing a pl/sql proc in oracle apex to display employee images in a template on basis of condition.

I am using for loop which would fetch images dynamically.

I need to add a background image that would include all the images, so i need help with the html code.
The images could be multiple so i need to fit them in the background image.

Snippet of the code(since original cant be posted) where background needs to be added:

```
<h2>Best Wishes</h2>';
for i in(select emp_id from emp where tochar(sysdate,'ddmm')=tochar(emp_bday,'ddmm')
loop
l_body:='<img width="500" height="500" src="URL"'||i.emp_id||'"/>
end loop;'
```

So, this would fetch all employee images with birthdays that day.
How can a background image code be added here?

P.S. Example if its birthday of 3 employees i want the 3 pics fetched from loop something like in the image below with background image of windows wallpaper.

The employee pics could be multiple depending on birthdays falling on that day , hence dynamic.

[image]

Comment: can you post a pic of what you mean when you say background image? It does not have to be an accurate example but it will be helpful on understanding what the expected outcome of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Image added for reference. So there's a background image and 3 pics on top of it. The 3/or as many as per loop condiiton need to be placed on the background image. So i need the html code for background image in this loop for holding those pics.

Comment: ok so What you need is a backgroun image for the element holding the images. so you should look at the css style ` <div style="background-image: url('your_image.jpg');"> `

Comment: Where do add this in my existing code and how? That's a challenge becaue of the plsql loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is sudo code since I don't have an exact example but you would want to do something like the below.

```
 <!-- this would go on the top of your page perhaps inside your head tag -->
 <styles>
    .bg {
      /* The image used */
      background-image: url("yourimage.jpg");
    
      /* Full height */
      height: 100%;
    
      /* Center and scale the image nicely */
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
  </styles>


  /*container div to hold images */
    <div class="bg">
    for i in(select emp_id from emp where tochar(sysdate,'ddmm')=tochar(emp_bday,'ddmm')
  loop
   l_html:='<img width="500" height="500" src="URL"'||i.emp_id||'"/>
  end loop;
</div> /* close image div*/
```

Comment: I tried but no image got added. <h2>Best Wishes</h2> <div style="background-image: url('your_image.jpg');">';
for i in(select emp_id from emp where tochar(sysdate,'ddmm')=tochar(emp_bday,'ddmm')
loop
l_html:='<img width="500" height="500" src="URL"'||i.emp_id||'"/>
end loop;

Comment: How does it determine the size of background image? And can it be defined using /inside img tag?

Comment: well thats more of a style question. But the answer is , if you want the background image to be the full width and heigth of the background container you can set the width and height to `100%` . Yes it can be defined on the img tag however in these cases I always use a `styles` tag to target elements on a webpage by either ID or Class.

Comment: Do you mind giving an example for img tag? Or if it can be included in the existing img tag for images?

Comment: And one last question: can the positioning of these dynamic images be modified? Like space between each image and so on?

Comment: I updated my response to kind of detail what I mean about setting the background image. The response to your last question , is yes, you can use javascript to adjust image positioning, if your not satisfied with the page layout after it renders.